# OpenCV: how to check if element exists in SparseMat

Tags: c++, opencv, sparse-matrix

I am using a `SparseMat` of `CV_32FC3` and am trying to do the following:

```
int dims = 2;
    int size[] = {10,10};
    SparseMat m = SparseMat(dims, size, CV_32FC3);
    m.ref<Vec3f>(2,5)[0] = 0.5;
    m.ref<Vec3f>(2,5)[0] = 0.5;
    m.ref<Vec3f>(2,5)[0] = 0.5;

    if(m.find(2,6) == m.end()){
        cout << " could not find 2,6" << endl;
    }
    if(m.find(2,5) != m.end()){
        cout << "found 2, 5" << m.ref<Vec3f>(2,5)[0] << ", " << .ref<Vec3f>(2,5)[1] << ", " << .ref<Vec3f>(2,5)[2] << endl;
    }
```

However, the find part is incorrect, how do I use this to check if an element at that index has been added to the sparse mat?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the definition of [SparseMat::ptr](http://www.docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#sparsemat-ptr):

```
C++: uchar* SparseMat::ptr(int i0, int i1, bool createMissing, size_t* hashval=0)
```

> Return pointer to the matrix element. If the element is there (it is
>   non-zero), the pointer to it is returned. **If it is not there and
>   createMissing=false, NULL pointer is returned.** If it is not there and
>   createMissing=true, the new elementis created and initialized with 0.
>   Pointer to it is returned. If the optional hashval pointer is not
>   NULL, the element hash value is not computed but hashval is taken
>   instead.

So in your code

```
m.find(2,6) == m.end()
m.find(2,5) != m.end()
```

should be

```
m.ptr(2,6,false) == NULL
m.ptr(2,5,false) != NULL
```